# Use switchyard property in jpa binding native query

Tags: java, jpa, switchyard

Lets say I have a property defined in my switchyard.xml

[image: Switchyard Property Definition]

If I have a JPA native query, also in my switchyard.xml that includes

```
(select sysdate + interval '720' minute from dual)
```

I would like to use the property in the native query such as

```
 (select sysdate + interval '{horizonWindowMinutes}' minute from dual)
```

Is there a way using switchyard that I can achieve this property substitution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly had it.  Just needed to add the $ sign at the start of the property substitution.

```
 (select sysdate + interval '${horizonWindowMinutes}' minute from dual)
```

Comment: Ah, I see, it was missing the leading `$`, as you say. When I reviewed the answer I missed that; my mistake, so I'll delete my comment, and have an upvote.